# Passing a pointer to an array of arrays to a function

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I have a main function which sets up the following variables:

```
double matrix[numVectors][size] = {
    {0.183963, 0.933146, 0.476773, 0.086125, 0.566566, 0.728107, 0.837345, 0.885175, 0.600559, 0.142238},
    {0.086523, 0.025236, 0.252289, 0.089437, 0.382081, 0.420934, 0.038498, 0.626125, 0.468158, 0.247754},
    {0.969345, 0.127753, 0.736213, 0.264992, 0.518971, 0.216767, 0.390992, 0.242241, 0.516135, 0.990155}
};

double result1[size], result2[size];

double *ptr_matrix  = &matrix[0];
double *ptr_result1 = &result1[0];
double *ptr_result2 = &result2[0];
```

What the above is *trying* to do is:

- Create an array with three rows of 10 doubles
- Create two empty arrays of 10 doubles
- Create a pointer to the matrix
- Create pointers to the two empty arrays

Then, I'm trying to pass all three pointers to another function. This other function will iterate over the matrix rows (only the rows, it doesn't visit the whole matrix space), perform a computation using the row (as an array). The end result is the two empty arrays declared at the beginning end up each becoming one row from the matrix.

Here is the prototype of the second function:

```
void smallestSum(double (*mat)[size], int num, double *first, double *second)
```

This function goes through each combination of the matrix rows (0/1, 0/2, 1/2) and checks the sums of their values. The two arrays producing the smallest sum eventually become `result1` and `result2` from above.

Seeing as this is the first time I'm really delving into pointer/array/matrix territory, I have a few questions:

- Am I correctly "getting" a pointer to the matrix? Or do I need to get a pointer to the first value of the matrix instead?
- In `smallestSum()`, can I iterate over the array as I would normally (using `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)`?

Comment: Use `vector<vector<double>>` then to pass to your function, `vector<vector<double>>& v` voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the definition of `ptr_matrix`, as it's not a pointer to a single double, but to the whole row:

```
double (*ptr_matrix)[size] = &matrix[0];
```

Then, you can call the function as follows:

```
smallestSum(ptr_matrix, numVectors, ptr_result1, ptr_result_2);
```

Inside `smallestSum`, you can iterate both over rows and over columns.

Note that `size` must be known at compilation time.

If the function doesn't modify the matrix, consider adding `const` to the type of its first argument.

Comment: Sweet, that worked. Makes much more sense. However, when iterating over the matrix, how would I dereference one of the rows to get the actual value of the row? I currently have `(*mat)[0]` (for the first row), but that's giving me a type of `double *`, whereas I want a `double[]`.

Comment: @MaxMackie You may use `double *` value as if it were `double[]`. To access a cell in the matrix, you can write `mat[i][j]` (`i` is the row index, and `j` is the column index).

Comment: Maybe I'm misrepresenting the error then. Within that function, I call another function to process two arrays (rows in the matrix). The prototype for that second function is `second(double a1[], double a2[])`. I figured that `double *` was causing a conflict with `double[]`. Is that wrong?

Comment: @MaxMackie A function parameter of type `double[]` is the same thing as a parameter of type `double *`. I think the problem is that you think that `(*mat)[0]` is the first row, but actually it is the first element of the first row. The first row is `*mat` or `mat[0]`.

Comment: Ahhh, I though you had to dereference the `mat` pointer to get to the first row. That makes much more sense. Thanks for filling the gaps!

Answer (score 0):

[The answer abacabadabacaba gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984887/7857987) is mostly correct except that `size` does not need to be known at compile time. If you include `size` as a parameter to the function you can use it as part of the type for other parameters to that function:

```
void smallestSum(int size, double (*mat)[size], int num, double *first, double *second)
```